# List item gets cleared immediately after it is entered in HTML+JavaScript To-Do List

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple HTML to-do list. Currently, the input works fine, it gets appended to the list but immediately gets removed. Is there something in my code that is causing it to do this?

```js
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
const li = document.createElement("li");

function newElement() {

  const inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  const t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must write something!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  let submitButton = document.createElement("submitButton");
  // submitButton.className = "close";
  submitButton.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(submitButton);
  console.log('function passed!')

}
```

```html
<h1>To-Do List</h1>
<form>
  Add to your to-do list here: <input type="text" id="myInput">
  <button onclick="newElement()" id='submitButton'>Submit</button>
  <button id='clearButton'>Clear</button>
</form>

</br>
</br>

<ul id="myUL">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's in a `form`. You forgot to `preventDefault()`.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the issue by getting rid of the form tag entirely. Also, I made sure to put all the variables into the function itself (for the JavaScript bit)

Here is my code:

```js
function addToList() {
 const li = document.createElement("li");
 const inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
 const inputText = document.createTextNode(inputValue); 
  li.appendChild(inputText);
 if (inputValue === '') {
     alert("ERROR! INVALID INPUT");
 } 
 else {
     document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
 }
 document.getElementById("myInput").value = " ";

 let submitButton = document.createElement("submitButton");
 console.log('function passed!');
 
}
```

```html
<h1>To-Do List</h1>



 <script src="toDoList.js"></script>


   Add to your list here: <input type="text" id="myInput">
   <button onclick="addToList()" id='submitButton'>SUBMIT</button>

 </br>
 </br>

 <ul id="myUL">
 </ul>
```

Comment: You don’t need to remove the `form` tag. Call `preventDefault` like the comments said.